# Warning in first Spring project

Tags: xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I`m a beginner in Spring. Do easy example "Hello World", but have a WARNING.

My  pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pavlo.firstspring</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenSpringdevcolibriFirst</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My HelloWorld.java

```
package com.pavlo.firstspring;    public class HelloWorld {
     private String message;



public void setMessage(String message){

     this.message  = message;
 }

 public void getMessage(){
     System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
 }
 }
```

My Beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">


    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.pavlo.firstspring.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My MainApp.java:

```
package com.pavlo.firstspring;


import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ApplicationContext context =
                new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("D:/MavenSpringdevcolibriFirst/src/main/resources/Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

        obj.getMessage();


    }
}
```

In console :

> Sep 22, 2016 4:38:11 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@238e0d81:
>   startup date [Thu Sep 22 16:38:11 EEST 2016]; root of context
>   hierarchy Sep 22, 2016 4:38:12 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file
>   [D:\MavenSpringdevcolibriFirst\src\main\resources\Beans.xml]
>
> Your Message : Hello World!

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by _have a WARNING_?

Comment: This logs are not warning. It is just INFO log messages

Comment: You don't have a Warning you just have some info logging which can be turned of you your logging configuration. Also if you're just starting with spring I would suggest not using Xml configuration as it is outdated.

Comment: Just an information: if you're a beginner, you should use Spring Boot and Annotation configuration. Forget XML configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Bob Brinks!